# Read in every line that starts with a certain character from a file

Tags: python

I am trying to read in every line in a file that starts with an 'X:'. I don't want to read the 'X:' itself just the rest of the line that follows.

```
with open("hnr1.abc","r") as file: f = file.read()
id = []
for line in f:
    if line.startswith("X:"):
        id.append(f.line[2:])
print(id)
```

It doesn't have any errors but it doesn't print anything out.

Comment: You've not stated whether your code works or what errors your have

Comment: shouldn't it be `id.append(line[2:])`? and please don't use **id** as the name as it's a builtin function

Comment: I changed it to `id.append(line[2:])` but it doesn't change any output.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

try this:

```
with open("hnr1.abc","r") as fi:
    id = []
    for ln in fi:
        if ln.startswith("X:"):
            id.append(ln[2:])
print(id)
```

dont use names like file or line

note the append just uses the item name not as part of the file

by pre-reading the file into memory the for loop was accessing the data by character not by line

Comment: Also if i wanted to read the content lines that started with "T:" but only the every first and second lines that begin with T:, how might i go about that?

Comment: Just keep a counter as they are found - that is starting to become a state machine - and that is a much bigger discussion

Comment: @gkusner: The name `line` is fine, but you should not use [`id`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#id) as an own variable name.

Answer (score 1):

Read every line in the file (`for` loop)
 Select lines that contains `X:`
 Slice the line with index `0:` with starting char's/string as `X: = ln[0:]`
 Print lines that begins with `X:`

```
for ln in input_file:
    if  ln.startswith('X:'):
        X_ln = ln[0:]
        print (X_ln)
```

Comment: While this might answer the question, you should [edit] your answer to include some explanation for why this solves the issue in the question. This makes it more valuable to those who come across the same issue later on.

Comment: Your code doesn't work because it doesn't answer the original question. *i am trying to read in every line in a file that starts with an 'X:'. I don't want to read the 'X:' itself just the rest of the line that follows.*

Comment: Karel, the code will print all lines,  that starts / begins  with 'X:'  prints complete line not just 'X:'

Answer (score 0):

```
for line in f:
        search = line.split
        if search[0] = "X":
            storagearray.extend(search)
```

That should give you an array of all the lines you want, but they'll be split into separate words. Also, you'll need to have defined storagearray before we call it in the above block of code. It's an inelegant solution, as I'm a learner myself, but it should do the job!

edit: If you want to output the lines, simply use python's inbuilt *print* function:

```
str(storagearray)    
print storagearray
```